# Reduction from ATM to ATM-co

Tags: turing-machines, computability

Is there a reduction from ATM to ATM-complement?

I have been thinking about it too much and couldn't find the answer.

I know that reduction from ATM-complement to ATM is not possible becouse if it was, ATM would not be in RE. But how can I proove/profe the other way around?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a purely theoretical question and is therefore a better fit at cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mapping reduction from (A<sub>TM</sub>)<sup>c</sup> to A<sub>TM</sub>. To see this, note that A<sub>TM</sub> is Turing-recognizable, so if (A<sub>TM</sub>)<sup>c</sup> ≤<sub>m</sub> A<sub>TM</sub>, we'd have that (A<sub>TM</sub>)<sup>c</sup> would be Turing-recognizable. But that's impossible, since we know that (A<sub>TM</sub>)<sup>c</sup> isn't Turing-recognizable, since if it were, A<sub>TM</sub> would be decidable (since any language that's Turing-recognizable and co-Turing recognizable is decidable).

However, there is a Turing reduction from (A<sub>TM</sub>)<sup>c</sup> to A<sub>TM</sub>. Just invoke the subroutine for A<sub>TM</sub> and return the opposite result.

Comment: I am so sorry, but by mistake I asked the opposite quetion..
I ment if there is a reduction from ATM to ATM-CO

Comment: @DvirSamuel Turns out it has the same answer. :-) Can you prove that if A <=M B, then A^c <=M B^c?

Comment: of course.. But pay attantion that ATM-Co is not really all the "rest of the world" that doesn't belong to ATM... What I mean is:
if you take your world as N, and A={1,2,3} so A-co is all the numbers except 1, and 3..
But here with ATM its'nt the same..

Comment: Can you define co-ATM for me? I've always seen it as the set complement of ATM.

Comment: ATM is the language that contains all (p,w) when p is a program/turing machine and p accept w and ATM-co is the language that contains all (q,x) when q is a program/turing machine and q doesn't accept x.

Comment: Maybe I am getting confused with something...
I am really thankful for your help :)